# Umount command unmount two mount points

Tags: osx

I have two mount point say, `/volumes/dir1` and `/Volumes/dir2`. When I `umount` one volume the other automatically gets unmounted.

The volumes are mounted from remote system. They output different file sizes with `df`command.

What could cause the issue. Is there anyway to know one is related to another. How do I check it?.

Is there any command to check the relations?.

Comment: Please, add to question example how you using umount cmd which gives you wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

You should umount by the directory name , not the device name.

```
man umount:

The  umount  command detaches the mentioned file system(s) from the file 
hierarchy. A file system is specified by giving the directory where it 
has been mounted. Giving the special device on which the file system 
lives may also work, but  is  obsolete,  mainly because it will fail in 
case this device was mounted on more than one directory.
```

Comment: @ljaz Khan I unmounted by the directory name only. I mean I did `umount /Volumes/dir1` ..

Comment: what is the output of `type umount`  and `which umount` , your mount command may be an alias for unmounting all

Comment: `which umount` returns `\sbin\umount`.

Comment: What r the contents of ur /etc/fstab , check that , if there is something wrong thr